# download_html() Error in basename(url) : path too long in R

Tags: r, xml2

I'd like to download some html code from sites web, but my R code retuns me this: `Error in basename(url) : path too long`

An example of url is: `https://www.amazon.com/VIZIO-1080-Smart-LED-D43-D1/dp/B01A0LGU3O/ref=sxin_3_osp20-8d5e1b7c_cov?ascsubtag=8d5e1b7c-b3a8-4018-9315-b01e2602c1af&creativeASIN=B01A0LGU3O&cv_ct_id=amzn1.osp.8d5e1b7c-b3a8-4018-9315-b01e2602c1af&cv_ct_pg=search&cv_ct_wn=osp-search&keywords=televisore&linkCode=oas&pd_rd_i=B01A0LGU3O&pd_rd_r=6ebe627b-37f8-4a8d-8d6b-e9b1fbb561f2&pd_rd_w=Sc4pX&pd_rd_wg=KAdJs&pf_rd_p=43ba9e17-96f5-4491-b054-e546013f7dc4&pf_rd_r=SR4SDFVDJP5YP89J9F7R&qid=1559599142&s=gateway&tag=bestcont06-20")`

if I use the function `download_html()` R returns back this `Error in basename(url) : path too long`

The url works, why R returns me an error?

Is there a way to bypass the problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `download_html()` uses `basename()` to generate a name for the output file:

```
download_xml(url, file = basename(url))
```

and `basename()` doesn't like the long URL - it's trying to use everything after the last `/` for a file name.

The easiest solution is to supply your own name for the output file:

```
download_xml(your_very_long_url, file = "myfile.html")
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the explanation. :)